# Adding a method to an Angular Javascript object made from ReST JSON call

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have an Angular application that get a 'person' from a rest call. In the config I have:

```
        when('/people/edit/:id',{
        controller:PersonEditCtrl,
        templateUrl: 'frontend/partials/people/person.html',
        resolve: {
            person: function(Restangular, $route){
                var theRoute= 'people/' + $route.current.params.id + '/';
                return Restangular.one(theRoute).get();
            }
        }
    }).
```

In the controller:

```
function PersonEditCtrl($scope, $location, Restangular, person) {

      $scope.person = person;
 }
```

In the html page, I use like this to show info:

```
{{person.firstName}}
```

In the html page, I would like to add some behavior to 'person'. For instance, I'd like to add a function that combines the first and last name. So, I'd like a function like getFullName(). Note that I am not making a person object, I am only getting the JSON from a ReST call. I'm assuming the a person object is getting made somehow, but I do not know how.

How do I add functions/methods to 'person' in how I currently have things?

Comment: You get the object from transforming the json response into javascript, since this is a normal javascript object, you can add methods to that object just like to any other object, through dot or square brackets notation.

Comment: In my controller, this is not working: $scope.person.foo= function(){return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName; }...should it?

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "not working"? Isn't the method added to the object, isn't the method visible in the view or does the method return incorrect data?

Comment: Not working i mean in the page, this does not print anything: {{person.foo}}

Comment: Because you don't call it. It's a function, so call it! ;D

Comment: i see, i just did {{person.foo()}} and it worked, but u knew that!...why don't u make an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: Nah, I'm fine, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set
     person.getFullName = function(){
        //Code here
     }